# Como llamar una variable de R a Python en Jupyter, utilizando la libreria rpy2

Tags: python, r

Buenos días a todos su apoyo con una consulta. Para jalar una variable de Python a R utilizando la libreria rpy2 se utiliza el siguiente código.

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cups_of_coffee': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
```

Después de generar la variable.

```
%%R -i df 
df_copia <- df
print(names(df_copia))
```

Y todo va bien, mi consulta es si existe alguna forma de hacerlo de forma inversa, una vez creada una variable en R, llamarla a Python, por ejemplo.

```
%%python -i df_copia
```

pddt: Al correr este código no obtengo la copia de la variable

Answer (score 0):

Consulta aquí, creo que te puede ayudar,

https://anderfernandez.com/blog/reticulate-usar-python-en-r/

Comment: Saludos @CMaya, las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad puesto que estas mismas podrían desaparecer a futuro convirtiéndose en enlaces muertos, por lo mismo es muy importante que se agreguen las partes importantes de éste y simplemente luego dejas el enlace como referencia.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/337668)